# bash comparing variables that are integers with -gt -lt

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script that reads integers from a file (one number per line, name of the file is passed as the script argument), finds maximum, minimum and sum. I've got a problem with the part, where I'm comparing variables, though. Code below (I've skipped here the part which checks whether the file exists or is empty):

```
#!/bin/bash

min=`cat "$1" | head -n 1`
max=$min
sum=0

lw=`cat "$1" | wc -l`

while [ $lw -gt 0 ]; 
do
  num=`cat "$1" | tail -n $lw | head -n 1`

  if [ "$num" -gt "$max" ] 
  then
    max=$num
  elif [ "$num" -lt "$min" ]
  then
    min=$num
  fi

  sum=$[sum+num]
  lw=$[$lw-1]
done

echo "Maximum: $max"
echo "Minimum: $min"
echo "Sum: $sum"
```

With this code I'm getting errors in lines 13 and 16: [: : integer expression expected

If I change the comparision part inside the while loop to:

```
  if [ $num -gt $max ] 
  then
    max=$num
  elif [ $num -lt $min ]
  then
    min=$num
  fi
```

I'm getting errors:
line 13: [: -gt: unary operator expected
line 16: [: -lt: unary operator expected

What am I doing wrong? I'm a total newbie in bash, so I'll be extremely grateful for any help.

Data that I used for testing:

```
5
6
8
2
3
5
9
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Probably* your input file contains DOS line endings or other improper formatting. Your code should work for well-formed inputs.

However, the proper way to loop over the lines in a file is

```sh
#!/bin/bash
min=$(sed 1q "$1")
max=$min
sum=0
while read -r num; do
  if [ "$num" -gt "$max" ] 
  then
    max=$num
  elif [ "$num" -lt "$min" ]
  then
    min=$num
  fi
  ((sum+=num))
done<"$1"

echo "Maximum: $max"
echo "Minimum: $min"
echo "Sum: $sum"
```

Notice also that backticks and `$[[...]]]` use syntax which has been obselescent for decades already.

Comment: Hi, you're right. I haven't noticed that I have a empty line in the testing data.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the expression

```
num=`cat "$1" | tail -n $lw | head -n 1`
```

assigns to num some value that is not a number in one of the iterations. I would suggest adding `echo "$num"` in the prev line to check this assumption

Answer (score 0):

Another thing: instead of reading lines using `cat | tail | head` it is easier to read file line by line using the following syntax

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
done < "$input"
```

This will read contents of `input` file into `line` variable.

See here for explanations about `IFS=` and `-r` https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/ - both of them not really necessary in your case